# python installing libraries NO pip

Tags: python

I own a domain and i can run python scripts. I can access ftp. I would like to use some libraries but i can't use the shall for installing pip packages.

How can i use python library without installing them using pip?

Comment: `pip --user ...` does not work?

Comment: i can't access the shall!

Comment: you can run python scripts. you so can access a shell with `os.system`.  and how do you run python scripts? you may need to give some more detail in your question if you want answers... what platform is the server on? how can you access anything? ...?

Comment: I own a domain and i can run python scripts. I can access ftp. I would like to use some libraries but i can't use the shall for installing pip packages.

Comment: 'owning a domain' informs nothing... what can you do on the server? how can you run python without a shell? if you want help, put that information in your question (and not in the comments down here!).

Comment: Do you mean something like you have Django, and can run python that way?  See @hiroprotagonist's question. To make the point more clear, you could describe in more detail what you do to run the python.

Comment: I have a folder named cgi-bin and to run a python script i call the www......./cgi-bin/helloworld.py and the script  runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the package file.
2. Use 7Zip (or some other compression utility) to open the file as an archive.
3. Extract the archive to a temporary directory.
4. Find the directory from the extracted archive that contains the name of the package and has a file called `__init__.py`.
5. Copy that directory to your Python\Libs directory (Windows it's `c:\Program Files\Python\Libs`)